# C++ и MySQL кодировки

Tags: c++, mysql

Решила использовать в программе на С++ MySQL.
И вроде бы даже кое-что получилось. Но возникло несколько проблем. 1ая - кодировка.
У меня выводятся для русского языка вопросики вместо текста. Таблица закодирована в cp1251_general_ci. Пробовала кодировать в utf но в БД их стооолько этих utf. Вообщем как я ни мучалась выводятся вопросики. Объясните, что нужно сделать? То что надо чтобы и там и там была одинаковая кодировка просьба не писать, это я и так знаю. Можно конкретнее?
И вот второй трабл, я так поняла с переполнением чего-то. Вообщем.. посмотрите, что я там наворотила.

```
#pragma comment(lib, "libmysql.lib") // подключаем библиотеку
#include <my_global.h> // Этот файл необходим для подключений заголовочных файлов, таких как windows.h, winsock.h и др. Заметь __LCC__ сверху исчезла
#include <mysql.h> // Заголовочный файл с описание функций
#include <stdio.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <Windows.h>

    using namespace std;
    int mysql(const char query[])
    {
        MYSQL mysql; // Дескриптор соединения
        MYSQL_ROW row; // Массив полей текущей строки
        MYSQL_RES *res; // Дескриптор результирующей таблицы
        MYSQL_FIELD *field;

        char host[] = "localhost"; // хост
        char user[] = "User"; // пользователь
        char passwd[] = "user"; // пароль
        char db[] = "it"; // название базы данных
        int port = 3306; //  порт. Если порт у сервера MySQL не по умолчанию (3306), то нужно указывать конкретный номер порта
        int num_fields;
            my_ulonglong num_rows;
        int i, l;

        mysql_init(&mysql);  // Инициализация
        mysql_real_connect(&mysql, host, user, passwd, db, port, NULL, 0); // соединение
        SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
        if (mysql_query(&mysql, query) > 0) // запорс. Если ошибок нет, то продолжаем работу
            {
                cout<<"Возникла ошибка"<<endl;
                // Если была ошибка, ...
                printf("%s", mysql_error(&mysql));  // ... вывдем ее
                return 1; // и завершим работу
            } 
        cout<<"При подключении ошибок не возникло"<<endl;
        res = mysql_store_result(&mysql); // Берем результат,
        num_fields = mysql_num_fields(res); // количество полей
        num_rows = mysql_num_rows(res); // и количество строк.

        for (i = 0; i < num_fields; i++) // Выводим названия полей
        {
          field = mysql_fetch_field_direct(res, i); // Получение названия текущего поля
          printf("| %s |", field->name);
        }

        printf("\n");

        for (i = 0; i < num_rows; i++) // Вывод таблицы
        {
          row = mysql_fetch_row(res); // получаем строку

          for (l = 0; l < num_fields; l++)
            printf("| %s |", row[l]); // Выводим поля
            //cout<<"| %s |"<<row[l]<<endl;
          printf("\n");
        }

        printf("Count records = %d\n", num_rows); // Вывод информации о количестве записей
        mysql_free_result(res); // Очищаем результаты
        mysql_close(&mysql); // Закрываем соединение
        return 0;
    }
    /*
    int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR args, int WinMode)
    {
        mysql("SELECT * FROM t_mid_author"); // Запрос
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }*/
     int main()
    {
        //SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
        //setlocale (LC_ALL, "Russian");
        //setlocale (LC_ALL,".1251");
        mysql("SELECT * FROM mas");
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: С setlocale (LC_ALL, "Russian"); в виндовой консоли тоже не работает ?  

А printf("Привет\n"); вместе с setlocale() в консоли ("Привет" в cp-1251) ?

Comment: не совсем поняла вопроса. (LC_ALL, "Russian") работает.
а вот про кодировки ничего не понятно

Comment: Ящитаю, `setlocale` и прочие `system("pause")` — очень плохой тон, которого нужно максимально избегать, и использовать только если оно гарантированно допустимо. В общем, нирикамендую такое, у меня от этого дрянья комп умер, потом брат [истории на ithappens](http://ithappens.ru/story/9139) писал с микроволновки.

Answer (score 1):

Про кодировки. Имеется в виду, что текст (русские буквы "Привет") набит в программе в кодировке cp-1251 (обычно так и есть в винде).

Тогда, если написали `setlocale()`, то в консольном окошке увидим русские буковки, а без `setlocale()` (или в названии кодировки ошиблись) увидим Ёштх (и еще 2 символа фигни).

Если `setlocale()` работает, а mysql выдает вопросы вместо русских букв, то надо искать аналог `setlocale()` для mysql.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Выполняем SQL-запрос
mysql_query(&link, "set names cp1251")
```

link - подключение к базе.
у меня сработало. выводит русский в консоль (при setlocale(LC_ALL,"Rus") естественно)

Comment: Плохо тем, что на системе без CP1251 (практически все *nix, не-русская венда) это или вообще не будет работать (под GNU/Linux, обычно, нет локали со странным именем «Rus») или будет выдавать черт знает что. По идее, универсально это должно решаться сугубо административно, без правок в коде — приведением локали соединения с MySQL к системной локали. Т.е., если не ошибаюсь, `default-character-set` в клиентской части `my.cnf`. Наверняка там `latin1` по-умолчанию.

А, ну да, и если кодировка локали какая-нибудь iso-8859-1, а надо выводить кириллицу — администратор системы ССЗБ.

Answer (score 0):

Ого, вопросы по MySQL резко набирают популярность. )

Смотри, я проверяю кодировку так printf("Тест");  INSERT INTO test(`text`) VALUES('Тест'); SELECT * FROM test;   - На экран выводится 2 русских "Тест", в БД "Òåñò", но в ней и кодировка по умолчанию: latin1_swedish_ci.  При cp1251_bin тоже ????, как и с кучей других кодировок. Во, можно использовать кодировку binary, но через phpmyadmin не посмотришь. Хм, с utf8_bin то же, что и с latin1_swedish_ci. В принципе, лучше установить кодировку utf8_bin и использовать функции для перекодирования текста из win1251 в utf8 и обратно.

Твой код работает. Что не так с переполнением?